# get file location when using dio get file

Tags: flutter, dio

I'm trying to download an sqlite file from my website so my Flutter app uses it within the application.

I need to know how to get the path of the downloaded file. Where are they stored? How do I get a handler or path string to where that sqlfile is?

Here's the code.

```
try {
  Response response = await Dio().get("https://mysqliteFile.sqlite");
  print('response is' + response.toString());

} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

// Construct a file path to copy database to
Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, DBassistanceClass.databaseName);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [download](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/download.dart) method to save the file in a specific path

```dart
await dio.download("https://mysqliteFile.sqlite", path);
```